# Move text in <p> to end of <p> width with only CSS

Tags: html, css, format

I have a line in a `<p>` element with a fixed width that looks like this:

```
<p class="line">
To be, or not to be, 
<span class="variant">that is the question,</span>
<span class="variant right">&nbsp<b>&minus;</b>&nbsp</span>
</p>
```

I am trying to move the `&minus;` "-" to the right end of the line with the rest of the text being left-aligned.  I need to do this only using HTML and CSS (preferably not CSS3) because I am making a mockup model.  I feel like there is a way to do it with  but I cannot think of what it would be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is absolute positioning an option?

Comment: Wouldn't a float:right work on your "right" css class?

Comment: Class `variantRight` should be `float:right`, look exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/dgW33/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
.right{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: How strange, I just tried that.  Thank you for proving me wrong though!  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yxC56/)**?

**CSS**

```
.variant.right {
    float:right;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="line">
To be, or not to be, 
<span class="variant">that is the question,</span>
<span class="variant right">&nbsp;<b>&minus;</b>&nbsp;</span>
</p>​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this separated from your HTML, you can do it this way (specifically, for the presentation layer, not the content layer)

```
p.line:after { 
    content: " - "; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    float: right;
}
```

​

```
<p class="line">
    To be, or not to be, 
    <span class="variant">that is the question,</span>
</p>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fch5J/6/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this has the added benefit of preventing the paragraph text from appearing above the `-`, should there be sufficient text. You're essentially creating a 'gutter' for the `-` to live in.

```
p.line {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 2em;
}
p .right { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 2em;
}
```

You can also add a `top` or `bottom` rule to `p.right` if you want the `-` to consistently show up in relation to the top or bottom of the paragraph block